# Flutter - Error: The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on Flutter 2.2.1 (channel stable). I reccently changed my SDK's environment from 2.7.0 to 2.12.0 (`sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`) in order to add plugins and I got a lot of errors (especially about *null safety*). One of them is about the extraction of data from firestore (I'm using `cloud_firestore: ^2.2.1`).

My code:

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('towns/${widget.townId}/beacons')
        .orderBy('monument')
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      final beacons = snapshot.data!.docs; // Error here
      return ListView.builder(
          physics:
              NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap:
              true,
          itemCount: beacons.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            if (beacons[index]['visibility'] == true) {
              return BeaconCard(
                title: beacons[index]['title'],
                monument: beacons[index]['monument'],
                image: beacons[index]['image'],
                duration: beacons[index]['duration'],
                distance: 0,
                townId: widget.townId,
                uuid: beacons[index]['uuid'],
                fontsizeValue: widget.fontsizeValue,
                languageId: widget.languageId,
              );
            }
            return Container();
          });
    }),
```

The error is about `docs` at the line `final beacons = snapshot.data!.docs;`:

> The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.

I'm a new flutter user, I don't understand what to do here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please provide the expected Stream type. In this case

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare that the builder `snapshot` parameter type is `AsyncSnapshot`.

For example:

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Only type

> AsyncSnapshot

in *builder* argument of streamBuilder with *snapshot*. Like this

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: *Your Code*
                     ,
    builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                                *Your Code*
                                                                }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please let flutter know the snapshot type inside the builder:

```
builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot)
```

Answer (score -1):

body: FutureBuilder(
future: usersref.get() ,
builder:(context, snapshot){

```
if(snapshot.hasData){
return ListView.builder(
itemCount:snapshot.data!.docs.length,   //here error
itemBuilder: (context,i){
return Text("");
});

}

if(snapshot.hasError){
}
else{
return Text("LOADING . . . .")
}
})
```