# How to get data from the firebase and store it into a list for futher manipulation in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = snapshot.data.docs;
_selectedSubjects = docs
    .map(
      (doc) => Subject(
        doc['SubjectName'].data(),
        doc['courseIcon'].data(),
        doc['courseCode'].data(),
      ),
    )
    .toList();
```

I have a class called subject that has attributes/members courseCode, courseIcon, and lastly subjectName. Everything is okay so far, but vs code is saying:

> Type: dynamic
>
> The property 'docs' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
> Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')."

I have already imported all the necessary libraries, as well as vs code's reccomendations. What should I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that `snapshot.data` *may* be `null`, so you need to first verify that it's not null before you can assign it to your non-nullable `docs` variable:

```
var querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
if (querySnapshot != null) {
    List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = querySnapshot.docs;
    _selectedSubjects = docs
        .map(
          (doc) => Subject(
            doc['SubjectName'],
            doc['courseIcon'],
            doc['courseCode'],
          ),
        )
        .toList();
}
```

The local `querySnapshot` variable is guaranteed to be non-null inside the `if` block, so now you can simply assign `querySnapshot.docs` to `docs`.

I also removed the `.data()` calls, as @Gwhyyy pointed out in their comment.

You might want to take a moment to read up on [nullability in Dart](https://dart.dev/null-safety) as you're likely to encounter many more situations where the type changes based on handling null.

Comment: I guess there is another error in trying to get fields as this  doc['SubjectName'].data()

Comment: I have followed your instructions and thanks for the link on nullability in Dart. I did learn a lot.

However I am still getting an error. A different one this time around
"Type: dynamic

The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'."

Comment: Never mind I have fixed the new error got help from [an answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70434475/12851785).